# Codeship Pro on_fail accross step

Tags: codeship

Is the `on_fail` directive of a step run when a previous step has failed ?

I'm using these steps :

```
- name: fail intentionally
  service: busybox
  command: false
- name: check if onfail is called
  service: busybox
  command: true
  on_fail:
    - command: echo reporting failure
```

Calling `jet steps` produces the following output :

```
(step: fail intentionally) 
(image: busybox) (service: busybox) Image exists, using cached image
(step: fail intentionally) error ✗
(step: fail intentionally) container exited with a 1 code
```

My `on_fail` is not run.

Is that an issue with the `jet` utility or would things behave the same in Codeship ?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined an `on_fail` contingency for the second test step (a step that will not fail). If the `on_fail` was set for the first step (which fails and stops the build), you would have noted the echoed statement.

This behavior would be consistent with a build running in CodeShip Pro.